# Does an accompanying spouse need to pay a fee to study in Denmark?

Tags: resident-permit, study, denmark

My wife has a residence permit in Denmark, as accompanying spouse. My residence permit is a normal work permit. This permit is not (yet) permanent; we've moved recently.

Is she eligible to study in Denmark free of charge? (She is looking for a Master's degree). I found [this information](http://studyindenmark.dk/study-options/tuition-fees-scholarships), and it looks like #2 is our case `Temporary residence permit that can be upgraded to a permanent one ("midlertidig opholdstilladelse mmf varigt ophold")`. But something in the wording is a bit weird, so I wanted to check, is this our case?

If yes, are there any other requirements that apply to her?

Comment: The wording is a bit tricky, but I believe that if she can meet the qualifications for permanent residence, even if she doesn't apply, then she will qualify for free tuition. The other way to interpret that is that the visa type itself is one that can eventually lead to permanent residence. But that would be inconsistent with the near universal requirement of residence to qualify as a 'home student' that most universities have.